# Retrofit get conversion error object

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit 1.9.
I have a custom RetrofitErrorHandler extending ErrorHandler.
I'm overriding handleError(RetrofitError cause) and I use cause.getKind() to find CONVERSION error.

Is there a way to find which object failed to be unserialized?

Example : 
I call the server to retrieve my user into a User POJO, but there is a conversion Error. I'd like to know that the conversion error is due to User.

Comment: to avoid all this kind of trouble, i suggest you to install a plugin in android studio i guess its named json to pojo. u can just copy/paste ur json and it will convert it to a class for you.

Comment: @k0sh I have to do this for Error Tracking purposes mainly to know if the json I receive has error (weird characters, etc. ). I can't use this plugin.