# Retrofit throws 'conversion' error for one of the responses

Tags: android, retrofit

I am fetching data using Retrofit,
In a synchronous request, I am getting response with code 200, 
but when it goes to de-serialize using my model class, it throws an error, problem is that for one input/response it parses the data, while for another input/response (from the same API) it throws `CONVERSION` type error.

I don't understand what causes a `CONVERSION` error.

Upon printing stacktrace, I got -

```
Sample-ProjectErrorHandler: conversion error
03-02 14:35:50.054 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err: retrofit.RetrofitError: Please try in few minutes
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:50)
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:     at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Please try in few minutes
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:     at com.discover.Sample-Project.api.Sample-ProjectErrorHandler.handleError(Sample-ProjectErrorHandler.java:77)
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:49)
03-02 14:35:50.064 17161-17161/com.discover.Sample-Project W/System.err:    ... 4 more
```

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34896624/retrofit-get-conversion-error-object)

Comment: Assuming that you have not overridden convertor in your(which is by default gson convertor)  check if the server response string is in valid format .you can validate your response http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: (I have validated the response using jsonschema2pojo.org, in two parts as my response was too large then their limit of 51200, my response looks properly formatted) .
I am new to Retrofit so couldn't figure out how to confirm whether default Gson convertor is changed or not)

Comment: interesting problem, unless i can see the response and your corresponding pojo structure its difficult to nail the problem.

Comment: Have any idea how I could show you the Pojos and response (considering Pojos are too many and response is too large to share here)